# Word 2007 - How do I get rid of an odd page break that splits up a table?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

Im working with Word 2007, and I have a table in my document.  The table spans a couple of pages.  On page 2, there is only the end of the prior row - which fills about 1/8 of the screen.  On page 3, there is a small row that appears at the top of the page (also taking up about 1/8 of the screen).

There is no page break on the page that I know of.  In fact, if I navigate between the two rows there appears to be no area between the rows at all.

Any thoughts?

Comment: when you display the hidden characters, you can't see anything ?

Comment: Have you tried re sizing the margins?

Comment: There are no hidden characters in the area...

Comment: I don't see any issues with the margins either...

Comment: Do you want it to span multiple pages? Does the table span all 3 pages and the third is the quirky one or does it span pages 2 and 3 and you would like it just to be on page 2?

Answer (score 0):

A work-around would be to save your table as a picture, then insert pieces of the picture (or play with scaling) to fit the space available in your document.